# Acitivity onDestroy not always called

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm developing a radio-streaming application and a homescreen widget.
The problem is when I kill the application, I want to modify the image in the homescreen widget like this :

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    //update widget
    WidgetIntentReceiver.updateWidgetFromActivityDestroy(getApplicationContext());

    mMediaPlayer.reset();
    mMediaPlayer.release();
    mMediaPlayer = null;

    System.out.println("End onDestroy -> stop stream");

    super.onDestroy();
}
```

But the code to modify widget is not always called (the 'System.out.println' not appears). I have already read that onDestroy is not always called.
But I don't find another solution ?

Thanks.

Comment: on what event u r trying to stop application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`is when I kill the application`. The  keyword here is `kill`. By kill you mean force close of the application as I understood. If so then you have no way to change something. Because when you force close the application or even if the OS kill your app on some reason (memory limits, battery optimizations, etc.) - there is no way to do something because the entire application process (with your package name) is simply killed by something like `Process.killProcess (int pid)` without any callbacks. And `onDestroy()` behavior in such moments is completely undefined. And it is written in the documentation:

`[..] There are situations where the system will simply kill the activity's hosting process without calling this method (or any others) in it, so it should not be used to do things that are intended to remain around after the PROCESS GOES AWAY.`

So don't forget that `onDestroy()` it is a method which is tightly bound to the `Activity's` lifecycle and not the whole application lifecycle. As a workaround you should create some `Base Activity` and in its `OnPause()` do the stuff you want and then make all other activities in your application inherit from it.

Other (bad solution which should not be used in production code) is to create a background `Service` which will in cycle check if your app is running with `actvityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();` and modify the widget if not.

Comment: Thank you Alexander for your detail response. You have right, by "kill" I mean, force close with the Application Manager in Settings.

The fact is that my radio-streaming running in background so if I "catch" onPause function, how I can do the difference between a simple press on "Home button" (radio-streaming continues to run) or a kill from Application Manager (radio-streaming has to stop and widget updates).

The application is available on the Play Store, so if you suggest me to not create a background Service, I will not :)

Comment: @Alex On stack overflow instead of thanks you can simply press accept button and other people will notice the answer."how I can do the difference between a simple press on "Home button" (radio-streaming continues to run) or a kill from Application Manager" - yes there will be no difference. By the way there is more correct ways from the point of application's design - instead of just killing your app with Application Manager - make some kind of Quit button in your application's main menu which will before finishing your app do some useful job - changing widget's icon or whatever else.

Comment: Ok for the button to accept your response ;)

I'll add a Quit Button but, my question about the kill action is not resolved and I have no idea on how to manage it :/

Comment: @Alex As I said in my answer you have no control on the app when OS kill it. So the conclusion here - you can't do something from the app if its process is killed.If you on some reason is extremely need to change something when your app is killed without calling onDestroy() - it is background service.